# Why variable `n` in Totient Function updated in every loop?

Tags: python, fractions

I have been working on finding all the reducible fractions for a given integer n.

For example, if the input is the number 5, the output is 4 because 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, and 4/5 are all reduced fractions. 5/5 is not a reduced fraction because it can be reduced to 1/1.

I have found a solution online (credits:geeksforgeeks) which is shown below, but I dont understand why is n updated every time in the while loop

```py
def phi(n):   
    # Initialize result as n 
    result = n  

    # Consider all prime factors 
    # of n and subtract their 
    # multiples from result 
    p = 2  
    while(p * p <= n): 

        # Check if p is a  
        # prime factor. 
        if (n % p == 0):  

            # If yes, then  
            # update n and result 
            while (n % p == 0): 
                n = int(n / p) 
            result -= int(result / p); 
        p += 1 

    # If n has a prime factor 
    # greater than sqrt(n) 
    # (There can be at-most  
    # one such prime factor) 
    if (n > 1): 
        result -= int(result / n) 
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link at [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20phi%28n%29%3A%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Initialize%20result%20as%20n%20%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20n%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Consider%20all%20prime%20factors%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20of%20n%20and%20subtract%20their%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20multiples%20from%20result%20%0A%20%20%20%20p%20%3D%202%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20while%28p%20*%20p%20%3C%3D%20n%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Check%20if%20p%20is%20a%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20prime%20factor.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28n%20%25%20p%20%3D%3D%200%29%3A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20If%20yes,%20then%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20update%20n%20and%20result%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20%28n%20%25%20p%20%3D%3D%200%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20n%20%3D%20int%28n%20/%20p%29%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20-%3D%20int%28result%20/%20p%29%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%20%2B%3D%201%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20If%20n%20has%20a%20prime%20factor%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20greater%20than%20sqrt%28n%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20%28There%20can%20be%20at-most%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20one%20such%20prime%20factor%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28n%20%3E%201%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20-%3D%20int%28result%20/%20n%29%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aphi%2816%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

`n` is updated everytime `p` is a prime factor. Meaning that the number of fractions can be reduced to a smaller prime. So we can think of `n` as the smallest prime factor in the initial request. We can think of `phi(16)` for example. If `n` is the smallest prime and `n > 1` then there can be only one prime that exists - otherwise it would've been caught in the while-loop.

I hope that helps!!!